# Angular 2 with ES6 and Promises not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, internet-explorer-11, systemjs

I have an Angular 2 app running fine on Chrome / Edge but it fails on Internet Explorer with the following error.

[image]

I am using the following index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">

    <script src="scripts/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/systemjs/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/systemjs/system.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular2/Rx.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lightbox/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/html5sql/html5sql.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } }
        });
        System.import('app/app/app.component');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <app></app>
</body>
</html>
```

The top 3 shims/polyfills should fix any missing functionality for IE as far as I can find. I'm not sure if it's the lack of native Internet Explorer support for Promises, ES6 or something else. I tried swapping all Promises to Observables but still the error remains.

Comment: promises aren't supported in IE11, does your shims for IE include the promise polyfill?

example: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise?

Comment: It is complaining about a syntax error in `app.component.js` but you haven't given us that file.

Comment: @Denis Tsoi I tried adding es6-promise but the error remains. I'll try that again though just in case.

Comment: Please always save and post screenshots as PNG not JPG

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with promises not working. In fact, they work very well: *they are reporting* the problem about the failed load/syntax error in `app.component.js` to you!

Comment: @Bergi I updated the image to png. There's no syntax error in app.component.js directly but probably somewhere in what it's referencing (the whole app). I'll continue to dig through all uses of promises to find the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the solution was mainly to change my TypeScript output to ES5 instead of ES6. Even though I was using various ES6 shims, this still wasn't enough for Internet Explorer to work.

UPDATE:

Changing the TypeScript compiler output to ES5 was done in the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you change typescript output to ES5?

Comment: @AkashJain Changing the TypeScript compiler output to ES5 was done in the `tsconfig.json` file. See updated answer for details.

Comment: Hey Chris thanks for reply, I already have this setting configured but still its not working on IE11. Do you think any other setting is required along with this?

Comment: @AkashJain Mainly the 3 shims / polyfills in my question code are needed. If it works on Chrome, these are the main thing needed for IE to work with ES5.

Comment: Ok Thanks Chris.